# Need some help on managing Strings

Tags: java, string, hashtable

Don't worry about the hash table guys but just give me some idea how to manage Strings.

I need to do spell check a word entered by the user in dictionary using hashtables. I got a method named checkDictionary() from hash tables to check whether the given word is present in dictionary or not. It returns a Boolean value if the word is present or false if not.

What I want to do is, I just want to check the word in dictionary when it is misspelled, making some possible corrections.

possible corrections :

Change one letter: For example, if the misspelled word is “kest”, i want to try all possibilities of
changing one character at a time, and look the modified word up in the dictionary. The
possibilities will be “aest”, “best”,...,”zest”, “kast”,...,”kzst”, etc.

---How can I change a single character at a time and that too from a to z.

Exchange adjacent letters: For example, if the misspelled word is “ebst”, try “best”, esbt”
and “ebts”.

---How can I change the adjacent letters , need to swap or something?..

Remove one letter: For example, if the misspelled word is
“tbird”, try all possibilities of removing one letter at a time, and look the modified word up
in the dictionary, which are: “bird”, “tird”, “tbrd”, and “tbir”.

---How can I remove each letter every time?

Please do remember that the word entered may be of any length.

I need to return this suggestions to the user after checking the words in dictionary.
Is there any methods in Strings that I can use to implement these functions.
Please help in implementing the above methods Change, Exchange and Remove.

```
     import java.util.*;
     import java .io.*;

     public class HashTableDemo
   {
     public static void main(String [] args)
  {

   // constructs a new empty hashtable with default initial capacity
     HashTable hashtable = new HashTable();
     Scanner keyboard = null;
     Scanner input=null;
     try
     {
        System.out.println("Enter a word to check in dictionary");
        keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String word = (keyboard.nextLine().toUpperCase());

     //Adding aal dictionary words from a text file to hash table.
        input=new Scanner(new FileInputStream("TWL.txt"));
            int i=1;

            // adding value into hashtable
            while(input.hasNextLine())
             {
             String hello = input.nextLine();
                            hashtable.put( hello, new Integer(i) ); 
             i++;
             }
      );


        if(hashtable.checkDictionary(word))
           System.out.println("The word "+word+" is there in the dictionary.");
        else
           System.out.println("The word "+word+" is not there in the dictionary.");
     }//try



     //Here I need to implement the required methods if the word is not in dictionary and misspelled.





         catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
           System.out.println("Cannot open file");
           System.exit(0);
        }//end catch
```

Comment: So are you just looking for how to manipulate strings?  Read the API documentation on java.lang.String.

Comment: First of all, format and fix your code. It does not even compile and looks horrible. Also you cannot put anything between the end of a try block and begin of a catch block...

Answer (score 2):

There is no simple solution for what you're trying to accomplish. A good mathematical concept you could use for spell-checking is called [Edit Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance), you should definitely read a bit of theory before attempting to write some code.